# interviewstreet median challenge

Tags: algorithm, median

**Problem**
The median of M numbers is defined as the 
1) if M is odd middle number after sorting them in order
2) if M is even the average number of the middle 2 numbers (again after sorting) 
You have an empty number list at first. Then you can add or remove some number from the list. For each add or remove operation, output the median of numbers in the list.

Example : For a set of m = 5 numbers, { 9, 2, 8, 4, 1 } the median is the third number in sorted set { 1, 2, 4, 8, 9 } which is 4. Similarly for set of m = 4, { 5, 2, 10, 4 }, the median is the average of second and the third element in the sorted set { 2, 4, 5, 10 } which is (4+5)/2 = 4.5

**My approach**
I think the problem can be solved in this way..
Idea is to use previous median value and pointer to find new median value instead of recalculating at every add or remove operation.

1) Use multisets which always keep elements in order and allow duplicates. In other words maintain sorted list somehow.

2) If the operation is add

```
2.1) Insert this element into set and then calculate the median

2.2) if the size of set is 1 then first element will be the median

2.3) if the size of set is even, then

           if new element is larger then prev median, new median will be avg of prev median

               and the next element in set.

           else new median will be avg of prev median and previous of prev element in the set.

2.4) if the size is odd, then

          if new element is larger then prev median

                 if also less then 2nd element of prev median ( 2nd element used to calculate avg

                    of prev median) then this new element to be added will be new median

                 else median will be 2nd element use to calculate the avg during last iteration prev

                    median.

          else

                 new median will be previous of prev median element in the set
```

3) If the operation is remove

```
3.1) First calculate the new median

3.2) If the size of set is 0 can't remove

3.3) If the size is 1 if the first element is the element to be removed, remove it else can't remove.

3.4) If the size of set is even, then

           if the element to be deleted is greater than or equal to 2nd element of prev median, then

               1st element of prev median will be new median

          else 2nd element of prev median will be the new median

3.5) If the size of set is odd, then

           if the element to be deleted is the prev median then find the avg of its prev and  next element.

           else if the element to be deleted is greater then prev median, new median will be avg of prev median and previous to prev median

           else median will be avg of prev median and next element to prev median.

3.6) Remove the element.
```

Here is the working code ...http://justprogrammng.blogspot.com/2012/06/interviewstreet-median-challenge.html. What are your views on this approach?

Comment: Your code is doing weird stuff when I remove the median, for instance: "4 a 1 a 1 a 1 r 1"

Comment: thanks ffao..that was small mistake, now corrected. But still there is some problem which i am not able to locate...

Comment: %g doesn't behave properly try it with larger values of median and x it will print in scientific notation

Comment: In a sorted data-structure, insertion/removal is a log(n) operation. The new median is going to be in the neighborhood of the old median and is a constant time operation; you need to check for a few cases.

Comment: @vsaxena right..that's what i am trying to do but not sure if my approach is correct or not

Comment: @amit.codename13 so what should i do to remove trailing zeroes(required in ques)

Comment: You are over complicating the median calculation. Look at my logic, it's much more simple. Use setPrecision to remove tailing decimal points.

Comment: @sachin Either there is no decimal part or the decimal part is .5. You can check for both cases easily, and print the right number of decimal places.

Comment: @all thanks guys..i was looking for problem in my approach....but not only i corrected that one, i also found another method to solve the problem... :)

Comment: My solution is here:
The problem is that it is not optimal - 3 test cases fail with running time exceeded-
Do you have ideas how to optimize it? This is the best I've done so far: http://pastebin.com/tfKZCsyV

Comment: OK Sorry - I saw that it could be optimized by having to sets - will change the code

Answer (score 4):

Your approach seems like it could work, but from the description and the code, you can tell that there is a lot of casework involved. I wouldn't like to be the one having to debug that! So let me give you an alternate solution that should involve less cases, and therefore be much simpler to get right.

Keep two multisets (this algorithm also works with two priority queues, as we're only going to look at the extremes of each one). The first, `minset`, is going to keep the smallest n/2 numbers, and the second, `maxset`, is going to store the last n/2 numbers.

Whenever you add a number:

- If it is greater than `max(minset)`, add it to `maxset`
- Otherwise, add it to `minset`

Note that this doesn't guarantee the n/2 condition. Therefore, we should add one extra "fixing" step:

- If `maxset.size() > minset.size()`, remove the smallest element from `maxset` and insert it to `minset`.
- If `minset.size() > minset.size() + 1`, remove the biggest element from `minset` and insert it to `maxset`.

After this is done, we just have to get the median. This should be really easy to do with our data structure: depending on whether the current n is even or odd, it's either `max(minset)` or the average between `max(minset)` and `min(maxset)`.

For the removal operation, just try to remove it from any of the sets and do the fixing afterwards.

Comment: all though the code above is working but it is not passing all test cases. for few it is wrong answer and for 2 it is time limit exceeded. So I am still trying to figure it out..But this is a nice approach.Thanks.

Comment: @sachin Your problems are caused by not checking if the iterator you got from the find() is valid before using it in the remove part. I also made some changes to the printing part, see fixed code here: http://pastebin.com/ECJ0Em0J

Comment: Thanks ffao..u were right that was the problem..now i will try to implement it using one multiset..:)

Comment: @viewers..ffao has proposed a better approach to solve the problem..u can look at code using links in comment..

Comment: view code here...[http://justprogrammng.blogspot.com/2012/06/interviewstreet-median-challenge-part-2.html](http://justprogrammng.blogspot.com/2012/06/interviewstreet-median-challenge-part-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is the comparison of each new item with the running median, which might be a calculated average value. Instead you should compare the new item with the value at the previous middle (`*prev` in your code). At it is, after receiving the sequence of 1 and 5, your median value will be  3. If the next value is 2 or 4 it should become the new median, but since your code follows a different path for each of those, one of the results is wrong.

It would be simpler overall to just keep track of the middle location and not the running median. Instead, calculate the median at the end of each add/remove operation:

```
if size == 0
    median = NaN
else if size is odd
    median = *prev
else
    median = (*prev + *(prev-1)) / 2
```

Comment: @viewers view code here [http://justprogrammng.blogspot.in/2012/06/interviewstreet-median-challenge.html](http://justprogrammng.blogspot.in/2012/06/interviewstreet-median-challenge.html)

Comment: @sachin The core of xan's suggestion is the same as mine, remove the casework. Less cases usually means better flowing code and it's a lot easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to verify two cases:

```
1) negative number
4
a -1
a 0
a 0
r 0

2) two big integer whose sum will exceed max int
```

Comment: nice test case, helped me to catch a bug!

Answer (score 0):

If your list is sorted, then you can calculate the median in constant time with a method similar to the following pseudo-code

```
if list.length % 2 == 0 
   median = (list[list.length/2 - 1] + list[list.length/2]) / 2 
else
   median = list[list.length/2]
```

Therefore, just maintain a sorted list on every insert/remove. You can do these operations in `O(n)` time by stepping through the list until you are between an element that is < the added element and one that is >= the added element. You can actually do these insert/removes in `O(log n)` time if you start in the middle of the list then decide if your element is less than or greater than the middle element. Take that half-list and start in the middle of that and repeat.

Your problem doesn't state what the performance requirements are for this but the entire thing cannot always happen in constant time as far as I am aware. This implementation has the following performance

```
Insert    O(log n)
Remove    O(log n)
Median    O(1)
```

Comment: The optimal solution is O(log n) on both insert and remove, while maintaining O(1) for the median operation.

Comment: i have used multisets from c++ in which insert and remove occur in O(logn) and finding median takes O(1) using the approach i said.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. If length % 2 == 0, then the list is of even length. Change it to != and it is correct. Also, you are using length/2 which gets truncated down, that's correct. But then you have length/2 - 1 which gets truncated down and lowered by 1. It should be length/2 + 1. If length/2 is 7.5, you want 7 and 8, not 7 and 6.

Comment: @JustinDanielson The logic is correct assuming the list is 0 based. If an array has length 8 (which is even) then you want the 4th and 5th elements, which will have offsets of 3 and 4 in a 0 based array. Same logic applies to the odd length.

Comment: @ffao You are correct, you can insert/remove in O(log n) if you do so in a binary search fashion. I will update the answer to be more complete, thanks

Comment: What data structure has O(log n) insert/remove and O(1) indexed access? I would think an O(1) median locator would involve remembering an iterator/pointer to the old median, like the original poster.

Comment: @xan You can do it with a simple array. Array lookups are constant time and you can insert/remove in O(log n) by starting in the middle and dividing the array by 2 until you find your insert/remove spot

Comment: I can see the lookup is log n, but how do you do the actual insertion without moving an average of n/2 elements of the array to make room?

Comment: @xan It would depend on your data structure and how the particular language implements it. If it was maintained internally (i.e. in memory) like a linked list it would just be a matter of updating the pointer of the previous element, which could happen in constant time. You have to remember nothing is actually "moving" in memory, just pointers being updated

Comment: That's what I meant about keeping a pointer, like the OP did. If you want to keep the O(log n) insert claim, you need to change your median pseudo-code to not use array indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This code solves the median challenge on interviewStreet.

```
# this code solves the median challenge on interviewStreet.
# logic is simple. insert the numbers into a sorted sequence in place.
# use bisection to find the insert index(O(logn)). keep a count of no. of elements in
# the list and print the median using it(O(1)).
!/bin/python
from bisect import bisect_left
List = [] 
nnode = 0 

def printMed():
if nnode>0:
    if nnode%2 == 0 :
    if (0.5*(List[nnode/2]+List[(nnode/2)-1])).is_integer():
        print int(0.5*(List[nnode/2]+List[(nnode/2)-1]))
    else:
        print 0.5*(List[nnode/2]+List[(nnode/2)-1])
    else:
    print List[nnode/2]
else:
    print "Wrong!"

def rem(val):
global nnode
try:
        List.remove(val)
except:
    print "Wrong!"
else:
    nnode = nnode-1
    printMed()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(raw_input())
for i in range(0,n):
    l = raw_input().split()
    if(l[0] == 'r'):
        rem(int(l[1]))
    else:
    index = bisect_left(List , int(l[1])) ;
    List.insert(index ,int(l[1]))
    nnode = nnode+1 
    printMed()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for median challenge in java using collections.sort(list)

```
import java.util.*;
public class SolutionMedian{
    ArrayList<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]){

        SolutionMedian m = new SolutionMedian();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();

        char[] op = new char[n];
        int[] val = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            op[i] = in.next().charAt(0);
            val[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            if(op[i] == 'a') 
                m.add(val[i]);
            else 
                m.remove(val[i]);
    }

void add(int val){
        sortedList.add(val);
        getMedian();
    }

    void remove(int val){
        int index = sortedList.indexOf(val);
        if(index>=0){
            sortedList.remove(index);
            getMedian();
        }else{ 
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }
    }

    void getMedian(){
        Collections.sort(sortedList);
        int size = sortedList.size();
        switch(size){
            case 0: 
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
                break;
            case 1: 
                System.out.println(sortedList.get(0));
                break;
            default: 
                if(size%2 == 0) {//even size
                    int halfIndex = size/2;
                    long sum = sortedList.get(halfIndex)
                              + sortedList.get(halfIndex-1);
                    if(1==(sum&1)) 
                        System.out.println((sum/2)+".5");
                    else 
                        System.out.println(sum/2);
                }else{//odd size
                    System.out.println(sortedList.get((size-1)/2));
                }
        }
    }
}
```