# Interviewstreet median challenge: Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve interviewstreet's median challenge. I saw a similar question posted here: [interviewstreet median challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007406/interviewstreet-median-challenge) but I want to find out what's wrong with my approach. I'm using binary search and a sorted ArrayList to find out median at each point. Only 1st, 3rd and 10th tests pass, rest all fail with Wrong Answer.
Question: http://pastebin.com/1QhbiB2U
Here's the code:

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long N = in.nextLong();
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        String op = in.next();
        long number = in.nextLong();
        performOperation(op, number, list);
    }
}

private static void performOperation(String op, long number, List<Long> list) {
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, number);
    if(op.equalsIgnoreCase("r")){
        if(index < 0){
            System.out.println("Wrong!");//Doesn't exist
            return;
        }else{
            list.remove(index);//Remove any one occurence
        }
    }else{
        if(index < 0){
            list.add(-index-1, number);//Add in sorted list
        }else{
            list.add(index, number);//Add where the same number exists, should still be sorted.
        }
    }

    if(list.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }else if(list.size()%2 == 0){
        double median = (list.get(list.size()/2) + list.get(list.size()/2 - 1))/2.0;
        if(median == Math.ceil(median))
            System.out.println((long)median);
        else
            System.out.println(median);
    }else{
        System.out.println(list.get((list.size()-1)/2));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question your code tries to answer?

Comment: Its there in the link I mentioned. Anyway, I've copied it here: http://pastebin.com/1QhbiB2U

Comment: Your link on pastebin doesn't work.

Comment: @KrackJack: Just curious, where are you sorting your List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is with output of doubles in attached program.
I verified that program from question for input:

```
2
a 1
a 1000000000
```

gives:

```
1
5.000000005E8
```

Such change works for above case ( although it's not very nice ):

```
long median = (list.get(list.size()/2) + list.get(list.size()/2 - 1));  // median is multiplied by 2
    if(1==(median&1))
        //odd
    System.out.println(""+(median/2)+".5");
else
    System.out.println(median/2);
```

And note that ArrayList.add with index is O(n).

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing :). Thanks for pointing it out, that was the problem.